# Wicket: How to Use Weekly Calendar

Tags: calendar, components, wicket

I use Wicket framework and I would like to know if there is a component which has weekly calendar feature.

Also, I would like to add appointments on runtime without using any other calendar services.

[I mean something like that](https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=cGQwY29vanBodDduc3Fib3Q3dTJxNW1jNDhAZ3JvdXAuY2FsZW5kYXIuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQ&gsessionid=OK)

I have googled it already but I haven't found a component which suits me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for Wicket + FullCalendar: https://github.com/42Lines/wicket-fullcalendar